# React Boostrap NavDropdown.Item closes modal when NavBar is closed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Hello i'm trying to open a `Modal` upon `NavDropdown.Item` click that is inside a `NavBar`,

If I do something like this

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { rockPositions } from "../../constant/markers"
import { CloseButton, NavDropdown, Alert } from "react-bootstrap";
import Modal from 'react-modal/lib/components/Modal';
import { RouteBadge } from "../RouteBadge/RouteBadge";
import { RouteTable } from "../RouteTable/RouteTable";
import { modalStyle } from '../RockModalMarker/RockModalMarker.css.js';

const RockDropDownModal = (props) => {

    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    const route = props.route;
    const rock = rockPositions.find(rockPosition => rockPosition.name === route.rock);
    const index = props.rockIndex;

    const toggleModal = (e) => {
        setIsOpen(!isOpen);
    };

    if (!isOpen) {
        return (
            <NavDropdown.Item key={index} href="#rock" onClick={toggleModal}><span className={"rock-name-dropdown"}>{route.rock}</span>: {route.name}</NavDropdown.Item>
        )
    }
    return (
        <Modal key={index}
            defaultStyles={modalStyle}
            isOpen={isOpen}
            onRequestClose={toggleModal}
            centered
            ariaHideApp={false}
        >
            <CloseButton variant="white" onClick={toggleModal} />
            <Alert variant="primary" style={{ marginTop: "20px", backgroundColor: "#01579B", borderColor: "#0277BD" }}>
                <Alert.Heading style={{ color: "#FFF" }}><p className="routeName">{rock.name}</p></Alert.Heading>
            </Alert>
            <RouteBadge rock={rock} />
            <RouteTable rock={rock} />
        </Modal>
    )
} 

export { RockDropDownModal };
```

the modal opens fine but it's behind the `NavBar` and if I close the navbar the modal closes too.

I was trying to close the navbar and only show the modal but and I wrap the dropdown item like this

```js
<Navbar.Toggle>
            <NavDropdown.Item key={index} href="#rock" onClick={toggleModal}><span className={"rock-name-dropdown"}>{route.rock}</span>: {route.name}</NavDropdown.Item>
</Navbar.Toggle>
```

it closes the Navbar but also the Modal.

In the screenshot [here](https://i.ibb.co/0qC0QF6/preview.png) you can see the NavBar, when the selected item is clicked the Modal should open and the navbar close.

How can I prevent the Modal from closing?

Comment: Please create or provide code to a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Why are you using react-modal, when react-nbootstrap already offers a Modal component? What is your version of react-bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

If one of the main problems here is that the navbar overlaps the modal, have you tried setting the **z-index** of the modal to a greater value? This would set the modal above the navbar and upon closing the modal, it will also close the navbar as well.

In addition to this, try to play around with **expanded** property of Navbar. You could create a state inside Navbar

```
const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(`default_boolean_value`)
<Navbar expanded={isExpanded}/>
```

where-in upon clicking a dropdown item inside the child component, you could set the state of the Navbar to **expanded=false**

here is the documentation, you can find **expanded prop** here https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/